# SearchView widget with GridView. I type in the search field, but it doeasn't refresh the GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview, widget, searchview

I'm new to coding. I'm trying to implement a SearchView Widget that should update a GridView, but it doesn't work. When I type something in the search field nothing happens. Nothing happens if I tap on the search button neither. Could you please help me?

This is the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private static Context mainContext;

    private FragmentDataSaver mDataSaver;
    private static final String DATA_SAVER_TAG = "DATA_SAVER";

    private View mDecorView;

    public ArrayList<Movies> mMovies;

    WallAdapter wallAdapter;

    GridView gridView;

    public static Context getContext(){
        return mainContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

        mainContext = getApplicationContext();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mDataSaver = (FragmentDataSaver)fm.findFragmentByTag(DATA_SAVER_TAG);

        if(mDataSaver == null){
            mDataSaver = new FragmentDataSaver();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(mDataSaver, DATA_SAVER_TAG).commit();

            mMovies = DatabaseProva.creaDatabaseProva();
            mDataSaver.setData(mMovies);
        } else {
            mMovies = mDataSaver.getData();
        }

        gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview_layout);

        /*if(savedInstanceState == null){
            mMovies = DatabaseProva.creaDatabaseProva();
        } else {
            mMovies = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("tempMovies");
        }*/

        wallAdapter = new WallAdapter(this, mMovies);
        gridView.setAdapter(wallAdapter);

        handleIntent(getIntent());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            //use the query to search your data somehow
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.search_view);

        // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        android.widget.SearchView searchView = (android.widget.SearchView) searchMenu.getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                wallAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                return false;
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        if(hasFocus){
            mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
    }

    /*@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("tempMovies", wallAdapter.getItems());
    }*/
```

The adapter (WallAdapter):

```
public class WallAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movies> implements Filterable{

    private ArrayList<Movies> tempMovies = new ArrayList<Movies>();


    public WallAdapter(Context context, ArrayList movies) {
        super(context, 0, movies);
        setItems(movies);
    }

    public ArrayList<Movies> getMovies() {
        return tempMovies;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<Movies> movies) {
        this.tempMovies = movies;
    }

    public ArrayList<Movies> getItems() {
        return tempMovies;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_view);
            holder.mImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final Movies currentMovie = getItem(position);

        holder.mImage.setImageBitmap(currentMovie.getImage());

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SchedaFilm.class);
                intent.putExtra("titolo", currentMovie.getTitolo());
                intent.putExtra("locandina", currentMovie.getIdLocandina());
                intent.putExtra("trama", currentMovie.getTrama());
                intent.putExtra("regia", currentMovie.getRegia());
                intent.putExtra("anno", currentMovie.getAnno());
                intent.putExtra("genere", currentMovie.getGenere());
                getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<Movies> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
            //constraint is the result from text you want to filter against.
            //objects is your data set you will filter from
            if(constraint != null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                // No filter implemented we return all the list
                filterResults.values = tempMovies;
                filterResults.count = tempMovies.size();
            } else {
                for(Movies m : tempMovies){
                    if(m.toString().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())){
                        tempList.add(m);
                    }
                }

                filterResults.values = tempList;
                filterResults.count = tempList.size();
            }


            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if(results.count == 0){
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            } else {
                tempMovies = (ArrayList<Movies>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{

        private ImageView mImage;

        public Context getContext(){
            return mImage.getContext();
        }
    }
```

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="arca.mitty.com.arcagridview"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                           android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SchedaFilm"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The Searchable xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:label="@string/app_label"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

This is the Movie class:

```
public class Movies implements Parcelable{

    private String mTitolo;
    private String mGenere;
    private Bitmap mLocandina;
    private Bitmap mLocandinaBig;
    private int mAnno;
    private int mIdLocandina;

    private String mTrama = "Seduto sulla panchina ad un bus-stop di Savannah, " +
            "Forrest Gump ricorda la sua infanzia di bimbo con problemi mentali e fisici. " +
            "Solo la mamma lo accetta per quello che è, e solo la piccola Jenny Curran lo fa sedere accanto a sé sull'autobus della scuola. " +
            "Sarà lei a incitarlo, per fuggire a tre compagnetti violenti, a correre, liberando così le gambe dalla protesi. " +
            "Attraverso trent'anni di storia americana vista con gli occhi della semplicità e dell'innocenza, Forrest diventa un campione universitario di football, " +
            "mentre è sempre più innamorato di Jenny che però lo considera un fratello. Assiste ai disordini razziali in Alabama ed incontra Kennedy poco prima dell'assassinio. " +
            "Si arruola quindi nell'esercito, dove fa amicizia con il nero Bubba, un pescatore di gamberi che gli comunica la sua passione. " +
            "Dopo un fugace incontro con Jenny che canta a Memphis, Gump va a combattere in Vietnam.";

    private String mRegia = "Bino Cicogna";

    //Constructor
    public Movies (String titolo, String genere, int locandina, int anno){

        mTitolo = titolo;
        mGenere = genere;
        mIdLocandina = locandina;
        mLocandina = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(MainActivity.getContext().getResources(), locandina, 90, 135);
        mAnno = anno;
    }


    protected Movies(Parcel in) {
        mTitolo = in.readString();
        mGenere = in.readString();
        mLocandina = in.readParcelable(Bitmap.class.getClassLoader());
        mAnno = in.readInt();
    }

    public static final Creator<Movies> CREATOR = new Creator<Movies>() {
        @Override
        public Movies createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Movies(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Movies[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Movies[size];
        }
    };

    public String getTitolo() {
        return mTitolo;
    }

    public String getGenere() {
        return mGenere;
    }

    public int getIdLocandina(){
        return mIdLocandina;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return mLocandina;
    }

    public int getAnno() {
        return mAnno;
    }

    public String getTrama(){
        return mTrama;
    }

    public String getRegia(){
        return mRegia;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String s = "";
        s = getTitolo() + " " + getGenere() + " " + getRegia() + " " + getAnno();
        return s;
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }


    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(mTitolo);
        dest.writeString(mGenere);
        dest.writeParcelable(mLocandina, flags);
        dest.writeInt(mAnno);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also post a code of `Movies` class?

Comment: do you want to filter using movie name?

Comment: @VasylGlodan I added the Movies class code.

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman I want to filter either by name, by genre, by year...any of this informations.

Comment: Please, remeber that "DatabaseProva" is a Database built just for testing. And in the Movies class you will find a String variable "mTrama" (that stays for "mPlot") that is the same for every movie for the same reason. I built a fake Movies Database just for testing.

Comment: guys, anyone there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of attempts, I've found the solution.

There was, obviously, a logic error: in the "filter" I was updating the wrong ArrayList of movies. The one that the adapter uses for building up the GridView in my app is "tempMovies" ArrayList.
In the "filter" I was using "tempList" and then updating "filterResults", but never updating "tempMovies". Even in the "getFilter" method.

Furthermore, I've found an easier to understand and to apply "filter" method. I'm using it and it works perfectly.

Here you are the code:

```
public void filter(CharSequence text){
    String query = text.toString().toLowerCase();
    tempMovies.clear();
    if(text.length() == 0){
        tempMovies.addAll(originalMoviesList);
    } else{
        for(Movies m : originalMoviesList){
            if(m.toString().toLowerCase().contains(query)){
                tempMovies.add(m);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I found it at this site:
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/

In the end, thank you again to all of you who tried to help. I hope my experience will be usefull to others.

Answer (score 0):

In your filter, you are doing this:

```
if (m.toString().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
   tempList.add(m);
}
```

Make sure `m.toString()` returns value that actually contains movie's name, if it doesn't that condition will always be `false` and `tempList` empty, and next code will be executed:

```
if (results.count == 0) {
    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
}
```

Comment: I added the Movies class, in which you can find the "toString" method. I think that it's correct.